# How do you create an <ArrayList> local variable?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to create an ArrayList as a local variable. I think I have it figured out, is the following code correct? Thanks.

```
public void setExample(){
ArrayList<String> example = new ArrayList<String>();      //local variable? 
}
```

Comment: yes its correct. dont you have access to a compiler/ide to check these things?
also note that in java 7 you can ommit the repeated <String> part and do new ArrayList<>()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every variable you declare inside a method is local variable and also its mandatory to initialize it before using it.